# Why aren't belt sanders with sanding frames available anywhere?

Tags: tools, power-tools, sanding

I'm not sure if this question is a fit for Stack Exchange, but I'll try to make it fit.

I bought a Bosch 1274DVS 10 years ago and I was able to get an accessory 'guide'.  The guide was a frame that went around the belt sander to help prevent 'digging' into a large work piece and helping keep it level.

My dad would like a belt sander with this optional guide, but my model is no longer available and last year I was able to find 1 that had it as an option.  I cannot find any right now.  While this isn't how people primarily use the belt sanders, I wonder why this VERY useful accessory isn't more widely available?  Do people feel confident enough to sand a large cherry tabletop unguided?  or are there other tools that have replaced the need for this?

Edit: Right after writing this question, I found the guides are called 'sanding frames'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, frames are a relatively rare accessory, but they do exist. I started with all belt sanders currently available at the time of this writing at Amazon (with good reviews) and Home Depot (in stock in stores or online), then looked for sanding frames. I have built a list [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cmuIlqmQAieNVtJEliVgOdNH50Fl5ZXDk2lQc7U1y-o/edit?usp=sharing). In this list:

- Red means frame definitely not available.
- Orange means frame probably not available.
- Green means definitely available.

Couple of notes:

- DeWalt, Milwaukee, and Bosch no longer manufacture belt sanders, at least not under those names (DeWalt and Black & Decker are the same company).
- There are sanding frames available for out-of-production sanders ([Amazon has some](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sanding%20frame), for example), I did not include those.
- Porter-Cable, Ridgid, Ryobi, and SKIL don't seem to have frames for any of their current sanders and the internet is full of people who are sad about this.
- Makita refers to sanding frames as "sanding shoes" instead, while Porter-Cable uses "sanding shoe" to refer to the base plate behind the belt.
- SKIL Europe has the ["Equalizer" frame](http://www.skileurope.com/ie/en/diyaccocs/accessories/1165/471/accessories-for-belt-sanders/_equalizer_-sanding-frame/) for the 7600, 7675, 7610, 7620, 7630. I did not check to see if those were still in production.
- Festool [does not seem to have 110V versions of their sanders](http://festoolownersgroup.com/ask-festool/bs-75-available-in-usa/msg203866/?PHPSESSID=qt12ip66vmholrslnn7u4duqg1#msg203866). You can generally find converters to your country's standard but they aren't always cheap.

If you don't feel like clicking links, here are the matching pairs I am currently aware of:

- Sander: [Makita 9404](http://makitatools.com/en-us/Modules/Tools/ToolDetails.aspx?Name=9404), Frame: [Makita 193072-3](http://www.makita.ca/index2.php?event=newaccessorydetailstemp&id=223)
- Sander: [Makita 9903](http://makitatools.com/en-us/Modules/Tools/ToolDetails.aspx?Name=9903), Frame: [Makita 193070-7](http://www.makita.ca/index2.php?event=newaccessorydetailstemp&id=223) <sup>†</sup>
- Sander: [Makita 9920](http://makitatools.com/en-us/Modules/Tools/ToolDetails.aspx?Name=9920), Frame: [Makita 193071-5](http://www.makita.ca/index2.php?event=newaccessorydetailstemp&id=223) <sup>†</sup>
- Sander: [Triton TA1200BS](http://www.tritontools.com/en-ZA/Model/TA1200BS), Frame: [Triton TBSIS](http://www.tritontools.com/en-GB/Model/TBSIS)
- Sander: [Black & Decker DS321](http://www.blackanddecker.com/products/power-tools/portable-power-tools/sanders/3-in-x-21-in-dragstertrade-belt-sander/ds321), Frame: [Black & Decker 478705-00](http://servicenet.blackanddecker.com/Parts/Detail/216879) ([picture](http://www.ereplacementparts.com/sanding-frame-p-99082.html))
- Sander: [Festool BS 75](https://www.festool.com/Products/Pages/Product-Detail.aspx?pid=570207&name=belt-sander-bs-75-e-set), Frame: [Festool FSR-BS 75](https://www.festool.com/Products/Accessories/Pages/Detail.aspx?pid=490827&name=Accessories-FSR-BS-75), also part of the "[E Set](https://www.festool.com/Products/Pages/Product-Detail.aspx?pid=570203&name=Belt-sander-BS-75-E-Plus)"
- Sander: [Festool BS 105](https://www.festool.com/Products/Pages/Product-Detail.aspx?pid=570212&name=belt-sander-bs-105-e-set), Frame: [Festool FSR-BS 105](https://www.festool.com/Products/Accessories/Pages/Detail.aspx?pid=490828&name=Accessories-FSR-BS-105), also part of the "[E Set](https://www.festool.com/Products/Pages/Product-Detail.aspx?pid=570212&name=belt-sander-bs-105-e-set)"
- <sup>†</sup> Reportedly no longer officially available.

The Black & Decker one is listed as a "replacement part" so I'm not sure if it actually comes with the sander or is an optional accessory.

At the current time, vendors for all of the above can be found fairly easily by searching the internet for the relevant model numbers.

Evidence suggests that sander / frame pairs come and go, so it's entirely possible that the future will have a completely different set. There does not seem to be any historical consistency to which lines of sanders have frames available. Also, the prices vary wildly, from $15 USD to $150 USD, so you might want to shop around a bit.

---

There are frames for out-of-production sanders floating around as well. E.g. [here is a DeWalt frame](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002232Q) for the DW430 and DW431 belt sanders. [Here is a Bosch frame](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000223H7) that fits the 1276D and 1276DVS.

[This frame](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000223HA) reportedly fits the [1274DVS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000223HB), which I'm assuming is the same setup you purchased in the past.

---

A note about sanding frames in general: While I've never owned one myself, reportedly the gotcha with sanding frames for large surfaces is that one side of the frame ends up sitting lower on the already-sanded part of the material. The [SKIL "Equalizer"](http://www.skileurope.com/ie/en/diyaccocs/accessories/1165/471/accessories-for-belt-sanders/_equalizer_-sanding-frame/) presumably solves this issue (it's only half a frame, a fact they seem to be extremely proud of as [they patented it](http://www.skileurope.com/general/en/products/innovations/patented-equalizer-sanding-frame/patented-equalizer-sanding-frame.html)). So I guess you have to be careful about where you apply pressure, trying to prefer the unsanded side.

Comment: This isn't a super great answer, sorry. I'll do some more digging later to find examples of available pairs with newer model belt sanders. Right now I'm chatting with Amazon support to figure out why their "sanding frames" category is full of car keys and overalls...

Comment: I chatted with Dell sales looking for laptops with expresscard slots. They kept sending me picture of SD card slots insisting I was not looking hard enough. I'm sure it is supposed to be a bundle: the keys are there so you can lock up the sanding frames when you are done and use the overalls to stay clean while working.

Comment: I also found a Ryobi and a Triton, but didnt see any new Ryobi's that matched the frame and the Triton appears to have customer service issues.

Comment: @bowlturner Check it. Makitas look promising, and the Black & Decker DS321 has a frame as well.

Comment: Awesome!  I'll be doing more checks on the Makitas.  I have given up Black & Decker myself, and the Triton had terrible reviews for customer service.

Comment: Was looking at Makita, it appears currently only the 9404 has the sanding shoe still officially available.

Comment: @bowlturner That's irritating; as the product pages for the 9903 and 9920 both still claim that the optional accessory is available. Maybe if you contact their parts department? I found the frames for the [9903](http://bcfasteners.com/shop/makita-193070-7-belt-sander-sanding-shoe/) and [9920](http://bcfasteners.com/shop/makita-193071-5-belt-sander-sanding-shoe/) available from a vendor in Canada. There are at least some US vendors as well, with comparably high prices. The DS321 is certainly becoming appealing.

Comment: @bowlturner On a hunch I checked Festool and both of their sanders (BS 75 and BS 105) are offered in an "E Set" that includes a frame as well. Dunno if they come in 110V versions but you could always get a transformer. I didn't even bother checking the price, I'm sure it's exorbitant.

Comment: @JasonC The festool are beautiful machines, but 440 pounds, closing in on $700.  Makes the Makita 9404 much more attractive at half the cost (with a sanding frame